# Augment properties with literal notation

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Let's assume I have the following CoffeeScript code:

```
person =
  name: 'Alice'
```

Now, I want to augment this object with two additional properties. The common way is to write:

```
person.age = 34
person.bestFriend = 'Bob'
```

However, I don't like repeating `person`. What I do like however, is writing:

```
person =
  age: 34
  bestFriend: 'Bob'
```

(Unfortunately) This creates a whole new object and assigns it to the person variable, meaning Alice has lost her name. Is there a nicer way to augment an object in CoffeeScript besides writing property assignments line by line? Something like:

```
person.augment
  age: 34
  bestFriend: 'Bob'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as a language feature, but writing a simple `extend` function is easy enough (or use an existing version [on Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)):

```
extend = (dst, src) ->
  dst[k] = src[k] for k of src
  dst

person =
  name: 'Alice'

extend person,
  age: 34
  bestFriend: 'Bob'
```